# Difference between local and remote host

Tags: sql, database

What's the difference between local and remote servers and how they function?

Comment: One is local and one is remote?

Answer (score 4):

A local server is located in the same machine as the one who made the request. A remote server is another machine that can receive and respond to exterior requests.

Comment: thank you @ErickMota and actually at which time do you actually start using remote servers ... I mean what is the criteria for switching from local to remove severs

Comment: @JayJunior it's whenever you actually do that based on the project you are working on. It's sort of like "When do you switch to decaf?" You switch to decaf when the situation calls for it.

Answer (score 0):

Local host is the current host in which you are logged in.
Remote host is the host to which you are trying to connect from the local host.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference between local and remote host. This is a consideration somehow relevant for a "client" to connect to a server.

Consider you have a private database with your books. You only access it from your private computer at home (same computer where the database is located). Then this is `local`. You address your database in this case typically by searching for `localhost`.

But now imagine you want to access your book database from your laptop, when you are travelling. The database is still at your home (and your computer there is running!). You either need to know the IP address of this home computer, or you better configure a DNS service to give your home computer a name "mygreatbooksdbathome.de". In addition you will then have to configure eventual port-forwards on your router (different topic....network setup) and firewall settings on your home computer to allow connections from outside (different topic ... security settings). But if you do all the work, you can then access your database from anywhere `remotely` by searching at `mygreatbooksdbathome.de`.

This is typically called "the internet" or so ;-)

If you understood this, you are free to run your server on any cloud hosting platform out there, write a nice client-app, and sell it to anybody interested in your book inventory (or whatever).